# Alternative to BufferedReader.readLine() in Java to output multiple lines of text

Tags: java, string, encryption, bufferedreader

I have an assignment to encrypt a text file given a key. I have it working, except that when I have a text file with multiple lines of text, the output is all on one line. I believe it is because BufferedReader.readLine() does not save end lines? Here is my code:

```
static void encode(File file, String key) throws IOException
{
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file); 
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader); 
    String current;  
    char content[] = {};
    StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(content)); 

    while((current=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null)  //this reads the file contents and calls our convertString method
    {

        for(int i=0;i<current.length();i++) 
        {
            content = new char[current.length()]; 
            if(Character.isLetter(current.charAt(i))) 
            {
               content[i] = convertString(current.charAt(i), key);
               string.append(content[i]); 
            }
            else 
            {
               content[i] = current.charAt(i);
                string.append(content[i]); 
            }
         }
     }
    System.out.println(string); 
    fileReader.close();

}
```

I know there is BufferedReader.read(), but that is a type int. I'm not sure if there is a simple substitute, or if I have to fundamentally change my code.

Comment: What on earth is the meaning  of your title? BufferedReader is for input, not output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the newlines yourself with

```
string.append("\n");
```

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I didn't think of that, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If content is all being printed on one line, in general look for a way to add "\n"